Elasticsearch multi query
I have ElasticSearch documents as follows
{
  "_id": "011ANHG820FQVE0PSUCDS2LAES04B81D",
  "_index": "testindex",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "Type": "Inbound",
    "ANI": "4912345678999",
    "DNIS": "4912345678988",
    "duration": 239000,
    "TAG": [
      {
        "name": "Recived_A",
        "userName": "Anton"
      },
      {
        "name": "Recived_B",
        "userName": "Anton"
      },
      {
        "name": "Closed_A",
        "userName": "Anton"
      },
      {
        "name": "Closed_A",
        "userName": "Anton"
      }
    ],
    "Call": [
      {
        "partitions": [
          "/A/B/C/D"
        ],
        "userName": "Anton"
      }
    ],
    "region": "DE",
    "startTime": 1610370256000,
    "stopTime": 1610370495000
  }
}

I need a query that includes 3 values.
The value TAG must be empty and must be resolved within a timeframe (startTime stopTime).
The empty value is already causing me the first problem.
I heed some hints for a good query

The Timeframe query is
{
"query": {
"range": {
"stopTime": {
"gte": 1725865650000,
"lte": 1725865680000
}
}
}
}

And the Mapping for TAG
"TAG": {
"properties": {
"name": {
"index": "not_analyzed",
"type": "string"
},
"userName": {
"index": "not_analyzed",
"type": "string"
}
},
"type": "nested"
},

Usually its easier for us to help you fix a problem with a query that you wrote!
